# Azure Text to Speech: Error code: 1007. Error details: SSML must contain a maximum of 50 voice elements

Tags: azure, text-to-speech, ssml

I use Azure text to speech and I got this exception:

```
Error code: 1007. Error details: SSML must contain a maximum of 50 voice elements. Actual 90.
```

But my SSML contains only 45 `voice` elements.

Answer (score 0):

Figured myself. Azure TTS service actually counting both `voice` and `audio` elements. Error description somehow misleading, it should be mentioning `audio` elements as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [batch synthesis api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/ai-services/speech-service/batch-synthesis) which doesn't have voice element count limit.